# Submit form method=post with multiple different value=xxx with similar name=x?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I need to retype a bunch of names written on a paper and make a digital copy of it to a computer (a txt file). Then copy/paste each name and submit it again into a website one by one. Type one name then submit, wait until the page reloads, then repeat again. I saved the html file of the website but I don't have access to website's server. I was thinking I could modify the html file I saved so I'll just copy/paste once then click submit once. I'm not sure if it's possible to copy the names from the text file and embed it in the html code or maybe make a code to read the names from the txt file.
Honestly, I don't mind copy and pasting the names one by one into the website. What slows me down is the page reload time and the website only has one input field. It takes a few seconds to reload after submitting one name. So I want to be able to copy paste all then submit it once. I saved a local copy of the html file of the website and added action="website.com/xxxx" so it submits it to the website even if the html file is saved on my computer. The code below is a part of the website's html code:

```
<form method="post" action="website.com/xxxx">
<input type="text" name="t" style="width:250px">
<button type="submit"><p>Submit<img src="submit.png" style="width:32px;vertical-align:middle"></p></button>
</form>
```

I was thinking if I could modify it like this:

```
<form method="post" action="website.com/xxxx">
<input type="text" name="t" style="width:250px" value="jane">
<input type="text" name="t" style="width:250px" value="jenny">
<input type="text" name="t" style="width:250px" value="mark">
<input type="text" name="t" style="width:250px" value="ben">
<input type="text" name="t" style="width:250px" value="cathy">
<button type="submit"><p>Submit<img src="submit.png" style="width:32px;vertical-align:middle"></p></button>
</form>
```

Comment: You're going down the right track, but that's not how web forms work. You can automate something like this, but it does need a little code or an automated tool to help. Unfortunately this isn't the kind of question we answer here.

Comment: Cannot do that. Write a script to fill in the values in the Form and submit it. This will not reduce the loading time, but you can run the script without supervision and drink a coffee while it is working

Comment: @mattmanser Could you suggest where I could post this and get answers?

Comment: @user1950929
Could you post a sample script?

Answer (score 0):

If you have PHP with HttpRequest installed, you can try something like this

```
<?php
$url = 'http://website.com/xxxx'; // url of the form action, not the form itself
$names = file('names.txt');
for($names as $name){
    $request = new HttpRequest($url, HTTP_METH_POST);
    $request->addPostFields(array('t' => trim($name)));
    $request->send();
}
```

If you have PHP but no HttpRequets, you can use [cURL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php), but I have absolutely no idea how it is working.
Other languages should have similar possibilities.

Comment: Hi, is this client side script?

Comment: What do you mean? It is just a PHP script, you can either run it via `php script.php` or place it in the htdocs of a Webserver with PHP and access it from the browser.

Comment: Hi, I don't have access to the website's server so I need a client side script.

Comment: You don't need access to the website's Server but PHP installed on your system.  What operating system do you have? In Linux install the packages php and php-http with your package manager, for Windows there should be an executable to download in php.net .

Comment: Just noticed it's a pecl extension, Installation process can be found in the comments in this site http://www.php.net/manual/de/http.install.php